# State server in webfarm scenario?

Tags: asp.net, session, stateserver

This is a fairly basic question about state server but assume there are 2 servers behind a load balancer. How do I configure the session state server?

So, I have machine1 and machine2. I would assume that I would need to install the state server on 1 machine only and then use the internal IP to refer to that machine. Is this correct? As oppose too, I would not install state server on both machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your scenario (and most webfarm scenarios), a single state server is right.

You could refer to it by the internal IP or setup a DNS entry for the IP on the internal network and refer to it using that.

Answer (score 0):

Single state server is mad as you have no fault tolerance, if it does down its game over.  You need a distibuted state server stored on both servers.